# find the same elements count of two sorted array using functional programming style

Tags: python, functional-programming

Example: 
Given nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 4], nums2 = [2, 3], return 2

I have the imperative style solution using python, the algorithm complexity is O(m+n) :

```
def sameElementsCount(nums1, nums2):
    count = 0
    len1 = len(nums1)
    len2 = len(nums2)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        if nums1[i] == nums2[j]:
            count += 1
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif nums1[i] < nums2[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
    return count

print sameElementsCount([1,2,3,4], [2,3])
```

how to do it using functional programming  higher order functions like (map/filter/reduce). make sure the 
algorithm complexity is O(m+n)

Comment: I am not sure what higher order functions can fit with your approach but as zen of python says, simple is better than complex, you can try this `len(set(nums1)&set(nums2))`

Comment: Is _sortedness_ an implicit requirement for your two lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use set intersection: `len(set(num1) & set(num2))`

Answer (score 0):

The answer `len(set(num1) & set(num2))` given in some posts is quick to write, but it computes the  actual set intersection when only its cardinality was needed. Moreover it does not highlight any use of functional programming style.

The following behaves exactly like your program but with a functional programming style :
the **while loop** is turned into a **recursive function** and the counters disapear to let place to a pattern matching over the lists.

```
def sameElementsCount(nums1, nums2):
    len1 = len(nums1)
    len2 = len(nums2)
    if len1 == 0 or len2 == 0:
        return 0
    elif nums1[0] == nums2[0]:
        return 1+sameElementsCount(nums1[1:],nums2[1:])
    elif nums1[0] < nums2[0]:
        return sameElementsCount(nums1[1:],nums2)
    else:
        return sameElementsCount(nums1,nums2[1:])

print sameElementsCount([1,2,3,4], [2,3])
```